# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Duplicate default namespace declaration

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

Not sure why I am receiving this after the webservice ran and I am trying to return back to my client side bean.  The webservice works perfectly outside of my webserver in SoapUI.

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Duplicate default namespace declaration.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,321] 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:764)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:623)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:128)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:671)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2177)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:2057)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1982)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:637)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:483)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:309)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)

Comment: [com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Duplicate default namespace declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug submitted to CXF

Answer (score 0):

Update the WSDL definition in SOAPUI and try, it seems that the SOAPUI project is a bit old, and you did some changes on WSDL after that.